# Using generics to create a hierarchical store of hierarchical objects

Tags: java, generics, collections

I'm developing a parsing/validation infrastructure to process objects
in my application. The parsing process is really fast and the
validation process is very slow and usually doesn't fail. The parsing
process produces an object `Foo` and the validation process
additionally produces `ExtendedFoo`.

```java
public class Foo {
    private Long id;
}

public class ExtendedFoo extends Foo {
    private Boolean isValid;
}
```

The output of the parsing process is stored in a class like this (there are other types of objects beyond `Foo`):

```java
public class Store {

    private Map<String, ? extends Foo> foos = new HashMap<String, Foo>();
    private Map<String, ? extends Bar> bars = new HashMap<String, Bar>();

    public Map<String, ? extends Foo> getFoos() { return foos; }
    public Map<String, ? extends Bar> getBars() { return bars; }

}
```

And this store is the minimum basic information needed for the
application.

When I want to run the additional validation I would like to use the
following structure:

```java
public class ExtendedStore extends Store {

    public Map<String, ? extends ExtendedFoo> getFoos() {
        return (Map<String, ? extends ExtendedFoo>) super.getFoos();
    }
    // bar is not extended since there is no validation
}
```

But the "Unchecked cast" is making me think that there is a better way
to solve this.

What is the java generic "idiomatic" approach to this problem?

Comment: Not an answer, but ... you're in for a world of pain if you use `Map<String, ? extends Whatever>` because you can't use this type to add anything to the map.  Just use `Map<String, Whatever>` or introduce a type parameter.

Comment: Without knowing more about your codebase, I would probably write an abstract method `validate()` for `Foo` that returned a concrete `ExtendedFoo` instance (at this point, I wouldn't extend `Foo` anymore, but make `ExtendedFoo` more of a response type object with fully encapsulated fields), which could return either an eagerly cached value or lazily validate on the fly. I would probably not use a map at all, either, and would use some custom objects and fields if the possible contained values are known ahead of time, and you're not using direct user input strings (bad!)

Comment: When you say: „*`// bar is not extended since there is no validation`*“, does that mean *`ExtendedStore`* will only ever work with *`ExtendedFoos`*?

Comment: „*…(there are other types of objects beyond `Foo`)…*“ — Does that mean that every time a new type of object is introduced into the application you plan on implementing another *`Store.getXXX()`* for every one of those new types?

Comment: There are relevant things missing. E.g., when you have a declaration like `private Map<String, ? extends Foo> foos = new HashMap<String, Foo>();`, how do you populate this map?

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts for a generic hierarchical store approach include:

1. Defining a subclass to handle deciding if the structure 'isValid' may be self limiting. One alternative is having the logic at the Store level instead of specific to the struct.
2. Instead of returning the underlying map, providing helper methods in the Store type may improve usability.

Including a sample approach for a generic type store below. The data is maintained in 2 maps, one holds the validated data and the other stores the parsed data. On creation, the parsedData map and a validation function are provided. When the user requests validated data, if it hasn't been computed it will be.

```
    public static class TypeStore<T>
    {
        private final Map<String, T> validData;
        private final Map<String, T> parsedData;
        private final Predicate<? super T> isValid;
        public TypeStore(Map<String, T> parsedData, Predicate<? super T> isValid)
        {
            this.validData = new HashMap<>();
            this.parsedData = parsedData;
            this.isValid = isValid;
        }

        public Optional<T> getValue(String key) { return Optional.ofNullable(parsedData.get(key)); }
        public Optional<T> getValidValue(String key) { return Optional.ofNullable(validData.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> getValue(k).filter(isValid).orElse(null))); }
    }
```

Then multiple TypeStores can be added to a configuration class

```
    public static class ApplicationConfig
    {
        public final TypeStore<Object>  type1 = new TypeStore<>(new HashMap<>(), elem -> { /*Expensive Operation*/ return true; });
        public final TypeStore<Integer> type2 = new TypeStore<>(new HashMap<>(), elem -> { /*Expensive Operation*/ return true; });
        public final TypeStore<String> type3  = new TypeStore<>(new HashMap<>(), elem -> { /*Expensive Operation*/ return true; });
    }
```

Some alternative approaches include:

1. Instead of maintaining 2 maps in TypeStore, copy the original Map and define type which keeps track of whether the type is valid.
2. Instead of performing validation as keys are requested, provide a mechanism for bulk validation.
3. ApplicationConfig may be expanded to allow the caller to request data of a specific type instead of providing access to the underlying maps. Ex:
   `public <T> TypeStore<T> getData(Class<T> type)`
4. Instead of passing a Predicate to the TypeStore, a Function<T, T2> may be provided which allows access to a transformed and untransformed version of the store (or alternatively, TypeStore may have a function 'transform' which returns a new TypeStore of the new type backed by the current TypeStore)

Comment: „*…multiple TypeStores can be added to a configuration class…*“ — Does that mean that every time a new type of object is introduced into the application you plan on implementing another *`TypeStore<>(new HashMap<>()…`* for every one of those new types?

Comment: Mostly, the AppConfig example was used because the original question used multiple maps in a 'Store' class. TypeStore seeks to provide differential access to an underlying type (ex: a validated and unvalidated view) where one of the views may be expensive to calculate (the validated view). In general, a TypeStore can be created and used where it is needed, but it can sometimes be nice to have config data in a common location.

Answer (score 0):

> „*…this store is the minimum basic information needed for the application…*“

That suggests the need for a unifying abstraction such as…

```
public interface Storable< MBI > { 
    
    MBI getMinimumBasicInformation( );
}
```

> „*…the "Unchecked cast" is making me think that there is a better way to solve this…*“

Good spot. *`unchecked warnings`* are a sign that a design needs to be refactored to be more type safe. [*I demonstrate here how I would approach such a refactor*](https://jdoodle.com/ia/1ds)…

```
public class Store< F extends Storable< MBI >, MBI > {

    protected Map< String, F > stored;
    …
    public Map< String,  F > getStored( ) { return stored; }
    
    public void store( String key, F storable ){  this.stored.put( key, storable); }

}
```

And a ***type safe*** implementation (***zero** `unchecked warnings`*)…

```
public class ExtendedStore< F extends Storable< MBI >, MBI > extends Store< F, MBI > {

    public ExtendedStore( ) { super( ) ; }
    
    public ExtendedStore( Map< String, F > stored ) { super( stored ); }
    
    @Override
    public Map< String, F > getStored( ) {
        return super.getStored( );
    }
}
```

Then an example of ***one*** of the things that it stores ([*see another one here*](https://jdoodle.com/ia/1ds))…

```
public class Foo implements Storable< Long > {
    
    protected Long id;
    
    @Override
    public Long getMinimumBasicInformation( ) { return this.id; }
}
```

I would process those IRL using streams more than likely. But since this a only simple experiment meant to merely kick around [*the basic idea*](https://jdoodle.com/ia/1ds)…

```
…
Store< Foo, Long > fooStore = new ExtendedStore< >( new HashMap< > ( of( "foo", new ExtendedFoo( 1L, true ) , "FOO", new ExtendedFoo( 2L, true ), "Foo", new ExtendedFoo( 3L, true ) ) ) );
        
Map< String, Foo > foos = fooStore.getStored( );
        
fooStore.store( "fuBar", new ExtendedFoo( 4L, true ) );
        
Store< Bar, String > barStore = new ExtendedStore< >( );
        
Map< String, Bar > bars = barStore.getStored( );
        
barStore.store( "bar", new ExtendedBar( "bar", true ) );
…
```